# Php url shortener with static htmls

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url-shortener

My htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?l=$1 [L]
```

and php:

```
<?php
$links = parse_ini_file('links.ini');

if(isset($_GET['l']) && array_key_exists($_GET['l'], $links)){
header('Location: ' . $links[$_GET['l']]);
}
else
    include ('index.html');
?>
```

In the links.ini I have short url and website url:

```
youtube1 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0"
youtube2 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wcLNteez3c4"
etc.
```

These files are in the root and url shortening works.

In the index.html I have menu with static html pages:

```
<a href="/" >Home page</a>
<a href="page1" >page1</a>
<a href="page2" >page2</a>
etc.
```

But when I click on them it only reloads index.html?

Any help will be appriciated!

I tried to put static html links into links.ini:

```
page1 = page1
```

but that doesn't work either... I get the *Page isn't redirecting properly* error.

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($links);`?

Answer (score 1):

When you look into error messages, you will notice

> PHP Warning:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in links.ini on line 1\n in /var/www/example.com/index.php on line 2

and when looking at `links.ini`, you will see a second equal sign `=` in the URL

> youtube1 = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0

So quoting the value, e.g.

```
youtube1 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0"
```

should make it work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for this, I added the youtube links for an example. The problem that I am having is that it doesn't open the static htmls (menu) in the index.html. I think the htaccess rules might be the problem?

Comment: No, they are not. I copied your example files verbatim to my test environment, and it redirects to the appropriate youtube video when I enter `http://www.example.com/youtube1` (after quoting in links.ini, of course). So the code works, and the problem is with either links.ini or index.html. Look into error.log for further hints.

Answer (score 0):

So i changed the php to this:

```
<?php
$links = parse_ini_file('links.ini');

if(isset($_GET['l']) && array_key_exists($_GET['l'], $links)){
header('Location: ' . $links[$_GET['l']]);
}

else if($_GET['l'] == 'index' | $_GET['l'] == 'page1' | $_GET['l'] == 'page2')
    include($_GET['l']. '.html');

else if($_GET['l'] == '')
    include('index.html');

else 
    include('404.html');

?>
```

I don't know how elegant this is...
If someone knows a better way...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [this simple url shortener](https://github.com/urigoren/simple_url_shortener), it's very similar to what you are doing, but with a json instead of an ini file.

The core is the `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php).+)$ /index.php?short=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```